# Loading new content into <body> and keeping input fields value from previous <body> state?

Tags: ajax, jquery, input, tumblr

I'm trying to make my own tumblr search (tags only) since their own search function doesn't actually work.

So I'm nearly there. It works, but I need the search field to keep the value of what the user searched for.

So if I search for "foobar", it loads the tumblr.com/tagged/foobar directly into my tumblr.com, but the search field still contains the term "foobar"

Here is my working code *except* for the code where I'm trying to insert the previous search term into the newly loaded

Thanks in advance.

```
<html>

     <head>
          <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
          <script type="text/javascript">
               jQuery(function($) {
                    $('#syndex').keydown(function(event) {
                        if (event.keyCode == '13') {
                           var syndex = $('input:text').val();
                           $('body').load("http://syndex.me/tagged/"+ syndex);
                           $(this).val(syndex); //this is what's not working
                        }       
                    });
                });
          </script>
      </head>

    <body>
         <div id="logo">
              <input id="syndex" type="text"/>
         </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this into the `complete` function which can be passed as a parameter to `load`.

http://api.jquery.com/load/

`Load` makes an AJAX call which is asynchronous.  You are trying to set the value prior to the content being loaded.

```
$('body').load("http://syndex.me/tagged/"+ syndex,function(){
    $('input:text').val(syndex);
});
```

Comment: I would also suggest using a more precise selector than `input:text`, perhaps the `id` (which I think is `#syndex`?).  This is unrelated to the actual question though.

Comment: This is why I <3 S.O. That makes total sense too. Thanks for explaining! It worked.